# How to fix the positions of table elements Angular.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, ngtable

I'm binding JSON data to `ng-table` using Angular.js.

If any value is null then positions for all columns gets disturb. How can I fix the data with column header?

See this Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ixvp8B0dRwOBDHflmu2j?p=preview

`Description` should be `null` but all values shifted to left.

Or, if all values are null for any property hide that particular column.

Comment: how about this http://plnkr.co/edit/GcO0Laa4bvd9EeAsXMv7?p=preview ?

Comment: AFAICS: Just remove all your ng-if checks on == '' || == null.

Comment: @PankajParkar make Id null structure goes wrong then :( see http://plnkr.co/edit/YjGPSy2uyqPC1NJhJvm4?p=preview

Comment: @MarvinSmit I can not remove all ng-if checks because `if all elements are null for any column what is the point to show those column I want to hide that column if all elements are null` see this http://plnkr.co/edit/no73IuuhsUoCTZrwFw5d?p=preview

Comment: @Neo yes..the `ng-if` are making problems..

Comment: I can not remove all ng-if checks because if all elements are null for any column what is the point to show those column I want to hide that column if all elements are null see this plnkr.co/edit/no73IuuhsUoCTZrwFw5d?p=preview

Comment: If you want to do this with `ng-if` would need to iterate all your data in controller (service) first and create a `column config` object. Use that `column config` to determine visibility

Comment: @charlietfl do you have any sample for it? if you able to show it using my question data it will be great thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to determine if a column is empty you need some sort of column configuration that gets created by iterating the data to see if all rows contain data for any of the headings (object keys).

Then you can use that column configuration array as the repeater for the `<th>` and `<td>`.

Example config:

```
[
  {
    "heading": "Id",
    "display": true
  },
  {
    "heading": "Title",
    "display": true
  },
  {
    "heading": "Description",
    "display": true
  },
  {
    "heading": "Test",
    "display": false
  }
]
```

HTML

```
<thead>
    <tr>
      <th ng-repeat="col in colConfig" ng-if="col.display">{{col.heading}}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in data">
      <td   ng-repeat="col in colConfig"  ng-if="col.display">
        {{item[col.heading]}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Example config create

```
  var keys = Object.keys(data[0]);

  function createConfig() {
      var validKeyCounts = {};
      var colConfig;
      keys.forEach(function (key) {
          validKeyCounts[key] = 0;
      })
      data.forEach(function (row, idx) {
          keys.forEach(function (key) {
              if (row.hasOwnProperty(key) && row[key] !== null) {
                  validKeyCounts[key]++;
              }
          })
      });

      colConfig = keys.map(function (key) {
          return {
              heading: key,
              display: validKeyCounts[key] > 0
          }
      });
      return colConfig

  }
```

I'm sure this could be optimized but is just a way to get started with functionality wanted

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/v1U9QCqUTzXOS4OcPxzV?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: i'm generating all html dynamically as you can see html code so how can i specify config ? is there any way to update my  current code?

Comment: Don't understand. This is creating html dynamically using `ng-repeat`

Comment: I knw but I have a nested grid also check this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/Ixvp8B0dRwOBDHflmu2j?p=preview

Comment: for example if `Id` column value is null in all column then I do not want to show `Id` column as all values are null. can you help me to achieve this?`(Id column is just an example there can be any column which is null)`

Comment: My example already does that. If it's something like all columns have empty array in a property you would need to check for `isArray()` and check length

Comment: Or are you asking how to do this for sub-grids also?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83669/discussion-between-neo-and-charlietfl).